# any information about apache camel route

Tags: java, apache-camel

I starting to get familiar with apache camel route. I noticed that it using some keyword such as :

```
fromF("twitter://search?type=polling&delay=%s&keywords=%s", delay, searchTerm)
    .to("log:tweet").to("websocket:camel-tweet?sendToAll=true");
```

I searched but couldn't find any explaination about this type:

`search?type=polling&delay=%s&keywords=%s`

and

`websocket:camel-tweet?sendToAll=true`

how they work? and where can i found all possible keywords that can pass in here?

Comment: It's the docs of the [Twitter component](http://camel.apache.org/twitter.html) you're looking for.

Comment: Those keywords are called URL parameters and they look Twitter specific, not directly related to Camel

Answer (score 0):

Try to start learning here:

http://camel.apache.org/user-guide.html

Especially the books are highly recommended.